# Manipulating a global variable in a function in python

Tags: python

Okay so ill apologize in advance if this question has previously been answered but I've looked thoroughly and cant seem to find anything that works. Im making a very simple game where you pretty much just have to guess a number between 1 and 1000 and if its incorrect the computer guesses a number either 1 above or below your guess. here is a function I've made to determine if the guess was too low

```
def numLow(userInput, low, high):
    while userInput < num:
        print ("The guess of {0} is low".format(userInput))
        compGuess = (userInput + 1)
        print ("My guess is {0}".format(compGuess))
        low = (userInput + 1)
        if compGuess < num: 
            print("The guess of {0} is low".format(compGuess))
            userInput = int(input("Enter a value between {0} and 
                         {1}:".format(low, high)))
        else:
            print("The guess of {0} is correct!".format(compGuess))
            print("I WON!!!")
            showTermination()
    return (userInput, low)
```

now my issue is that i want to change the global variables userInput, low and high in the function. ive tried inserting

```
global userInput
global high
global low
```

before the function but it doesnt seem to work and if i put the globals inside the function i get "name 'userInput' is parameter and global". now im guessing the while loop is causing the problem but i cant seem to troubleshoot it. Im totally new to coding so i apologize if im breaking any coding rules or anything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: why do they need to be global variables?

Comment: the `global` directives would belong *in the function*, if you really wanted to do it that way. However, then you cannot make them parameters, since parameters are always local variables. Why are you trying to use both?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `userInput` as both a local and global variable in your`numLow()` function?

Comment: Since you're returning the new value of `userInput`, why don't you just assign it in the caller? `userInput, low = numLow(userInput, low, high)`

Comment: @Barmar all i did was add that now the whole program works. thanks for the help!!!!!

Comment: You mean you didn't know a function can return values?

Answer (score 0):

`userInput` for example is an input parameter to your function. The error message says exactly what the problem is here. You wanna use a global variable called `userInput` and you have an input parameter called `userInput` which are two different things for python. When `userInput` should be global then just define it somewhere globally like `userInput = None` and then instead of reaching it into the function as parameter just write in the function `global userInput` and python will know you are referencing to the globally instantiated variable. Both at the same time does not work.

Comment: Same holds for your other two Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use `globals()` like this:

```
globals()['userInput'] = ...
```

Comment: Bad idea.  By not even using the `global` directive, you've added a new dimension to the age-old advice to avoid using global variables.

Comment: @PaulCornelius :) I know. I am just trying to show how it can be done if OP *really, really* wants to do it.